# VB.Net Programmatically set DataGridViewComboBox .ValueMember on Rows.Add

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, combobox

I am trying to programmatically set the value of a DataGridViewComboBox when I populate the grid, but I keep getting an error about not being able to sort the combobox - "ComboBox that has a DataSource set cannot be sorted. Sort the data using the underlying data model."

I am not trying to sort the data of the combobox, I am simply trying to set the value member when I perform the Rows.Add function.

EDIT** The entire column should contain the same combobox items, and is not row specific.

```
Public Sub LoadComboBox()
Dim comboBox = New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)

    Try
        //myStepTable = data ' SQL query to get ID and Step

        For Each row As DataRow In myStepTable.Rows
            comboBox.Add(row.Item("StepID"), row.Item("Step"))
        Next

        'colStep is the defined name of the combobox column
        colStep.DataSource = New BindingSource(comboBox, Nothing)
        colStep.DisplayMember = "Value"
        colStep.ValueMember = "Key"
End Sub

Public Sub LoadGrid()
    LoadComboBox()
    myDataTable = data 'SQL query to get row data

    For Each row As DataRow In myDataTable.Rows
        dgvRecipeSteps.Rows.Add(row.Item("RowID"), row.Item("StepID"))
    Next
End Sub
```